# Getting HTTP Compression (GZip) to work with URL Routing on IIS 6

Tags: iis-6, gzip, url-routing, compression

I haven't seen any questions specifically addressing this specific issue.

When URL Routing is used, The Request goes into IIS and then is routed to the Aspx Page. For example, a site: www.site.com/products may route the request to wwwroot/inetpub/mysite/pages/productsPage.aspx

It's important to note that the page is ROUTED, not ReDirected.

Note that to get the URLs to work properly in IIS 6, a **Wildcard extension** has to be set up which routes all resources to Asp.Net (Asp.Net will then hand static resources back over)
This is documented here:
http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

It would appear that IIS doesn't GZip the content when it sends it back.  I have followed the instructions here:
http://www.kavinda.net/2007/02/17/how-to-enable-http-compression-iis6.html

to enable IIS 6 compression.

**Any idea why Http Compression doesn't seem to work? It seems to work fine on other sites on my server.  Just the one with URL Routing isn't working**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your ASP.NET application gzip its output itself with a method like [this one](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2007110401&page=1).

Comment: Great Code Snippet! I'm going to try it and if it doesn't work, try HttpCompress. I think this is exactly what I'm looking for though!

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is use [HttpCompress](http://blowery.org/httpcompress/) by Bel Lowery. It's a simple, free and open source HttpModule handling the HTTP compression of your pages. You can use it in combination with the IIS Http Compression option.

I use HttpCompress in combination with Vici MVC and it works smooth!

I've been searching the net for hours and it was either use HttpCompress, buy a commercial project (Port80 Software has a solution) or write my own HttpModule.

PS: IIS does HTTP compression based on the file extension. That's why it's not working for websites using URL routing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this way ?
[MS KB322603](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B322603&x=7&y=13)

To enable IIS 5.0 to compress .aspx pages, follow these steps:

1. Open a command prompt.
2. Type net stop iisadmin, and then press ENTER.
3. Type cd C:\InetPub\adminscripts, and then press ENTER.
4. Type the following, and then press ENTER:
     CSCRIPT.EXE ADSUTIL.VBS SET W3Svc/Filters/Compression/GZIP/HcScriptFileExtensions "asp" "dll" "exe" "aspx"
5. Type the following, and then press ENTER:
     CSCRIPT.EXE ADSUTIL.VBS SET W3Svc/Filters/Compression/DEFLATE/HcScriptFileExtensions "asp" "dll" "exe" "aspx"
6. Type net start w3svc, and then press ENTER.

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing, yes.  That turns on file compression for IIS (I'm using IIS 6, btw) for those extensions for ALL sites.  Other sites ARE working.  Just the one that serves Extensionless URLs is not working

Comment: You may try this way. It worked on our IIS 6.0

Comment: Thanks. I think it has to do with the extensions. IIS6 doesn't compress extensionless files, which is what routing is.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be that late on the discussion, but since I (still) have to enable IIS 6 compression on a MVC site, here is an IIS 6 native solution I have found:
Include in compressed extensions `axd`. This suppose you have IIS 6 extension less URLs support from .Net framework 4 correctly enabled.

I have done that directly in IIS Metabase. (As explained [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/http-compression-and-iis-6-0.html); `%windir%\systems32\inetsrv\metabase.xml`. Prior to edit it, stop IIS or enable "metabase hot editing" in IIS, and backup it.)

Extract from my configuration:

```
<IIsCompressionScheme   Location ="/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/deflate"
    HcCompressionDll="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"
    HcCreateFlags="0"
    HcDoDynamicCompression="TRUE"
    HcDoOnDemandCompression="TRUE"
    HcDoStaticCompression="TRUE"
    HcDynamicCompressionLevel="9"
    HcFileExtensions="htm
        html
        txt
        xml
        css
        js"
    HcOnDemandCompLevel="10"
    HcPriority="1"
    HcScriptFileExtensions="asp
        dll
        exe
        cgi
        aspx
        asmx
        ashx
        axd"
>
</IIsCompressionScheme>
<IIsCompressionScheme   Location ="/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/gzip"
    HcCompressionDll="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"
    HcCreateFlags="1"
    HcDoDynamicCompression="TRUE"
    HcDoOnDemandCompression="TRUE"
    HcDoStaticCompression="TRUE"
    HcDynamicCompressionLevel="9"
    HcFileExtensions="htm
        html
        txt
        xml
        css
        js"
    HcOnDemandCompLevel="10"
    HcPriority="1"
    HcScriptFileExtensions="asp
        dll
        exe
        cgi
        aspx
        asmx
        ashx
        axd"
>
</IIsCompressionScheme>
<IIsCompressionSchemes  Location ="/LM/W3SVC/Filters/Compression/Parameters"
    HcCacheControlHeader="max-age=86400"
    HcCompressionBufferSize="8192"
    HcCompressionDirectory="%windir%\IIS Temporary Compressed Files"
    HcDoDiskSpaceLimiting="TRUE"
    HcDoDynamicCompression="TRUE"
    HcDoOnDemandCompression="TRUE"
    HcDoStaticCompression="TRUE"
    HcExpiresHeader="Wed, 01 Jan 1997 12:00:00 GMT"
    HcFilesDeletedPerDiskFree="256"
    HcIoBufferSize="8192"
    HcMaxDiskSpaceUsage="99614720"
    HcMaxQueueLength="1000"
    HcMinFileSizeForComp="1"
    HcNoCompressionForHttp10="FALSE"
    HcNoCompressionForProxies="FALSE"
    HcNoCompressionForRange="FALSE"
    HcSendCacheHeaders="FALSE"
>
</IIsCompressionSchemes>
```

Rational: under the hood, extension less URLs work in IIS 6 by calling an `eurl.axd` page. See this [blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx) for a more in depth explanation on extension less URLs in IIS6 with fx4.